# GridSplitter cause height of ContentController to change?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, gridsplitter

When I start to change the height of grid using GridSplitter, the height of ContentController inside Grid below the GridSplitter started to cause problem.

Sorry if my question is not clear. Referring to my image is much easier to see the problem. Thank You for your help.

Initial Image

[image: Image when GridSplitter has not been started]

Second Image

[image: Image when GridSpliter has started to be used]

As you can see below the gridSplitter, the content has been distorted.

Image when i use both grid index '0' and grid index '2' row height to be AUTO - the problem over here is I can`t set the minimum height of the bottom grid

[image: Both row is set to AUTO]

Code for this part.
P/S, the content controller will switch the userControl and the userControl Height and Width has been set to AUTO.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Black">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="180"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Name="gridListboxAndButton">
                    <ListBox
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        Width="0"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Name="designControlListBox" 
                        Background="Black"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        Padding="0,10px,0,5px"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource keyDesignTemplateFromResources}">
                    </ListBox>
                    <Button
                        Name="btnSaveDesign"
                        Style="{StaticResource saveButtonStyle}"
                        Width="0"
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"
                        Height="40"
                        Content="{StaticResource buttonSaveContent}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        Click="btnSaveDesign_Click">
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
                              Height="5" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="gridDesignToolboxProperties" 
                      Background="Black" 
                      Width="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Padding="0,10,0,0"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Text="PROPERTIES"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock
                        Padding="0,10,0,0"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Text="VALUE"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        Name="contentSection" 
                        Background="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: And with the second approach when you move `GridSplitter` down your bottom `Grid` just moves out of the parent border?

Comment: @Maxim, Yes, even when i put the minHeight="", it just doesnt stop. Any solution for that?

Comment: When I last time got into this situation I just set `MaxHeight` for the first row definition. This solution is not universal, but in my case it was an appropriate one.

Comment: @Maxim Thx maxim. It works. Though i dont understand why when settingthe min height of bottom grid, it doesnt work. But when setting max height to top it works.

Comment: Welcome to the club of those who knows that using of `GridSplitter` in real applications is pain :)